# XPage : Add a styleClass to a given styleSheet of a XPage

Tags: css, xpages

How do I add a styleClass to a given XPage styleSheet ?

```
.required {
    background: red;
}
```

I want to do the same as Knut Herrmann answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657347/xpages-change-background-color-of-edit-box) but unfortunately it is not shown how to add that class to the XPage styleSheet (resp. edit that styleSheet). So how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a css file in database's `Resources / Style Sheets`

[image]

and add this css file as resource to your XPage in XPage's property "Resources".

[image]

Comment: I added a new css file named `myStyles.css` and added the required class. Then in the XPage EditBox I added the class like you did    `dojo.addClass(element, "required")` but to a `testButton` mouse onClick event . When I preview the XPage in my webbrowser and hit the testButton I do not see the expected effect. Then when I view the page source code I do not see myStyles.css file imported. Should'nt it ?

Comment: Add your css file path to XPage's Resources.

Comment: I did ... under Resources I see `myStyle.css` and in the css file I added the class.

Comment: Relating not seeing `myStyle.ccs` beeing imported I found the reason. One need to add the css file manually to the XPage. It is described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_styles_apply_to_page.html).   But still I see no effect in the webbrowser ...

Comment: That's what I said: add it to XPage's Resources :-)

Comment: Well to be precise, it seems not to be enough to create and add a ccs file under `Resources -> StyleSheets`but one needs to go to the desired Xpage, display the `Properties - Style` , select `Add style sheet to page...` and add finally the file via the presented file dialog. A bit complicated but obviously the recommend way. Anyway I accept your answer becaus you gave the crucial hint.

Answer (score 3):

1) Create your own stylesheet file in your database (e.g. `custom.css` under `resources/stylesheets`)

2) Now you can add a new `styleclass` to your stylesheet file or you can overwrite an existing styleclass

**Overwrite example:**

*XPage:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/custom.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="Hello"></xp:text>

</xp:view>
```

*custom.css:*

```
.xspTextComputedField {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

**"New" example:**

*XPage:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/custom.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="Hello" styleClass="customXspTextComputedField"></xp:text>

</xp:view>
```

*custom.css:*

```
.customXspTextComputedField {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20pt;
}
```

Comment: Relating overwrite expamples. As I wrote above in my comment to Knut Herrmans answer I do not see myStyle.css file in the source code of the loaded HTML file. When I look In my Xpage source code I also do not see myStyle.css according to your the code example. Do I need to insert the resource link manually ?

Comment: Relating not seeing `myStyle.ccs` beeing imported I found the reason. One need to add the css file manually to the XPage. It is described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_styles_apply_to_page.html).   But still I see no effect in the webbrowser ...

Comment: What do you mean you see no effect?

As in the style is not being applied, or the stylesheet is not appearing in the source HTML of your page?

If it is the latter, make sure you refresh the page with CTRL+F5 to clear the cache and see if that helps.

If the stylesheet IS being loaded with the page, post the source code of your input box. It should look like this:

<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="Hello" styleClass="customXspTextComputedField"></xp:text>